¿Cómo actualizar SQL usando AJAX y POST con datos obtenidos de un script?
Tengo un problema con un pequeño script que obtiene la Tasa Representativa del Mercado (TRM) de una moneda. Todo funciona bien hasta ese punto. Ahora deseo actualizar una fila llamada "rate" en la tabla "currencies" "con ID = 1" cada vez que se visita la página y se obtiene la TRM.
Para lograr esto, lo que intento es enviar el valor de la TRM a PHP mediante AJAX utilizando el método fetch para que el servidor procese la solicitud y actualice la base de datos, pero por alguna razón no funciona!
Revisando el error.log del servidor pude notar el siguiente error:

Undefined array key "rate" in trm.php on line 7

Dicha linea es la que empieza con: if ($_POST['rate'])
Por alguna razón no esta tomando los datos del TRM del script, necesito ayuda!
<?php 
require 'datab.php'; 
$outPut=array(); 

if ($conexion) { 
    try { 
        if ($_POST['rate']) {
            $rate = $_POST['rate'];
            $datos_trm = "UPDATE currencies SET rate = ? WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1"; 
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($datos_trm); 
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $rate); 
            $stmt->execute(); 
            $outPut['datos_trm']=$stmt->affected_rows; 
            $stmt=null; 
            $conexion=null; 
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($outPut);
            exit;
        }
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        echo $e->__toString(); 
    } 
} else { 
    echo 'No hay conexion a la BD'; 
} 
?>
<html lang="es"> 
<body> 
    <div id="rate"></div> 

    <script> 
    const url = "https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/mcec-87by.json?$limit=1"; 
    const request = new Request(url); 

    fetch(request) 
    .then(response => { 
        if (response.status === 200) { 
            return response.json(); 
        } 
    }) 
    .then(json => { 
        const rate = json[0]; 
        if (rate !== undefined && rate.valor !== undefined) { 
            const value = new Number(rate.valor).toFixed(2); 
            document.getElementById("rate").innerText = value.replace('.', ','); 

            fetch('trm.php', { 
                method: 'POST', 
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                }, 
                body: JSON.stringify({ rate: value }) 
            }) 
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Error en la solicitud');
                }
            })
            .then(data => console.log(data)) 
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)); 
        } 
    }) 
    .catch(_ => { 
        document.getElementById("rate").innerText = "..."; 
    }); 
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>


Cual es el problema?

Estoy intentando actualizar una fila de una base de datos con la información obtenida de un script, pero el código no funciona como debería.

Tenemos que ver la llamada de AJAX

en la primera carga ( que renderiza el form ) ni el rate ni el post existen, cambia el condicional a if ($_POST['rate']??false) { asi si no existe defaultea a false

en vez de if ($_POST['rate'])   debiera ser if (isset($_POST['rate']))
